# Django-model-utils: Use InheritanceManager with custom querysets

Tags: django, django-models

I use [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) for it's InheritanceManager class, so that querysets of my parent model `Activity` also return information from their subclasses like `Sports`, `Party`, etc.

However, now I want to make a custom query to add some filters by default, and I cannot get this to work for the InheritanceManager. Since the InheritanceManager already replaced my model's default manager, I cannot make a custom manager as described by [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

Simply inheriting the custom manager from InheritanceManager doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, just define your own custom manager class that inherits from `InheritanceManager`, like so:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class CustomInheritanceManager(InheritanceManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # your custom queryset here ...

class YourModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomInheritanceManager()
```

Comment: I could swear I've tried this exact solution before (even with `get_queryset` instead of `get_query_set`), but then it didn't work. Now it does, so thanks!

Comment: I used to custom manager to do some annotation by default, but this messed up the model's save function, since the annotated values where seen as legit database columns on save. So my code didn't work after all. Too bad.